# Are the two codes equivalent?

Tags: java

Suppose i have the following code, PS:its not complete consider it as pseudocode and the toString() is implemented:
I am trying to rewrite the code in main in one line, my try was to create an anonymous class and do the operations on it.
My approach in rewriting main into one line:

```
System.out.println (((new StudentList(aList)).setSORT(QSort)).dosort());
```

The pseudo java program:

```
public interface SortStrategy { int sort( List list ); }
public class BSort implements SortStrategy {
public int sort( List list ) { /* bubble sort ... */ } }
public class ISort implements SortStrategy {
public int sort( List list ) { /* insertion sort ... */ } }
public class QSort implements SortStrategy {
public int sort( List list ) { /* quick sort ... */ } }
/* etc. */
public class StudentList implements SortStrategy  {
private List listData;
private SortStrategy SORT;
public void setSORT ( SortStrategy s ) { SORT = S;}
public void dosort(){ SORT.sort(listData); }
public StudentList e ( List listData ) {
    this.listData =listData;
    Sort = new BSort();
}

public void print() { System.out.println(listData); }
}

public vayne
{
public static void main(String [] args){
     List aList;
    StudentList Stu = new StudentList(aList);
    stu.setSORT(QSort);
    stu.dosort();
    stu.print();
}
}
```

Comment: Since there is no `aList` in your code I would say both are equal in triggering a compiler error.

Comment: void return type has no method `dosort`

Comment: You're also trying to call methods on the results of methods with a `void` return type, which will never work. If you want to chain those calls they need to return something.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I encourage you to properly format (indent) your code. That will make it easier for people to understand and give you feedback.

Comment: cant i call the do sort on the anonymous object itself? i mean thats why i have the brackets to chain it

Answer (score 0):

The "dosort()" is performed on what is returned by "((new StudentList(aList)).setSORT(QSort))" i.e. what is returned by "setSORT()" method which is "void" so the codes are not equal as in the original code "dosort()" is performed on "stu" object.

Comment: @Misu is it really required that you accomplish this in a single line, or is this some sort of thought experiment?

Comment: @CaitLAN Jenner yes, is it possible to implement it if perhaps i changed the return type of sort? how can i call the function dosort() on the anonymous object instead?